# Generating colloids / nano-particles from palladium and platinum wire

Tags: electrochemistry, nanotechnology, colloids

I know I can generate colloidal silver from the following link
[generate colloidal silver](https://www.instructables.com/id/Colloidal-Silver-Generator/)

I now have 2 palladium and 2 platinum wires and would like to make one colloidal solution of palladium and one colloidal solution of platinum both in distilled water.  I watched a video on doing this [making platinum nanoparticles link](https://youtu.be/biQy_s6uixU) but no specifics were given on how it was made, did they use AC / DC voltage, what was the amperage used, and can it be made in distilled water and if so how?

Anyone have suggestions or steps I should follow?

Comment: ...Why do you want to make colloidal platinum and palladium?

Comment: @StianYttervik I want to compare their anti-bacterial effects in a colloidal solution https://www.nature.com/articles/s41467-017-02502-3

Comment: That link with the silver nanoparticles is questionable enough, and I don't want to say aloud what I think about the guy with the platinum abusing F. Mercury. I like amateur science, but it should aim to be scientific, not "look here I have no idea what I did but I'll post a video anyway". Sorry.

Comment: Sorry @RickT but you can't say you have obtained nanoparticles just for seen a black solid appear. You need to use TEM or at least (only in some cases) UV-vis technique

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A reliable method to obtain metallic nanoparticles in general is to reduce a metallic ion in presence of a capping agent. For a example, a traditional method to obtain gold nanoparticles (AuNPs) is to reduce a gold salt in presence of dodecanothiol.

For example, [here](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/nl0343405) is a method to obtain Pd nanoparticles by thermal decomposition, still the precursor is a Pd complex and the method requires a capping agent. (TOP stands for trioctylphosphine)

[image]

Related to the videos you post, it is not common or recommendable to obtain single metallic nanoparticles by an oxidation process (oxidizing the wires for example), it goes against what a metallic nanoparticle is. Electrolytic processes can be used to obtain metallic nanoparticles, but still using a salt as precursos as you can see [here](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10800-010-0234-3). You have to end with the reduced form of the metal if you want pure metal nanoparticles like the ones you cite in Nature's article. The videos you show do exactly the opposite and I can assure you that what is formed there aren't nanoparticles. Also, you are talking about Pt and Pd and their oxidation is not a simple task.

You can't confirm that you have nanoparticles just by checking Tyndall's effect, it doesn't work like that. You need to determine the size and the shape of the nanoparticles directly, using TEM or by indirect relation between them with another property, like light scattering or surface plasmonic resonance.

Even if you can [oxidize those wires](https://pubs.rsc.org/-/content/articlelanding/1961/tf/tf9615700123/unauth#!divAbstract) you probably won't end up with metallic nanoparticles. Because to maintain them at nanometric scale you'll need a capping agent. In the best case you'll obtain the metallic oxide or hidroxide and it will be in the bulk form.

I strongly encourage you to check articles in any of the ncbi websites https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/, https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/ and others which are free and peer reviewed.

Answer (score -1):

I use a very similar process as colloidal silver. 30 volts, I added sodium carbonate solution (with distilled water) a pinch of sea salt, blue berry extract.... Three droppers full in a 1000 ml beaker. Two platinum wires. I'm letting it go about 5-6 hours then adding my reducing agent. ( Manuka honey in distilled water) one dropper full. Sorry measurements aren't super precise but maybe someone else can be specific for times, amounts and measurements so you can calculate the ppms. I'm kind of winging it. Good luck! Same for palladium. Also for iridium, indium and copper. Different extracts but that's your choice. I like watermelon in copper, and turmeric extract in silver. Blueberry is good in the others... platinum will take the longest, 8-12 hours. I watch for the color change and clean wires every hour or so.